# Getting the current rotation and location coordinates

Tags: c++, opengl, coordinates, glut

I have a simple OpenGL program that allows you to "spawn" triangles and quads then move them around using your mouse and some keyboard controls to make complex objects, kind of like a 3D model editor.

What I'm trying to do is to get the vertex coordinates' current "location" and also their rotation, so I can write them to a file for saving and loading. The goal is to make a 3D model editor, save the model to a file and load the file into another OpenGL program I wrote.

Comment: You *generate* them. What's there to get? You already know everything you want.

Comment: How do you draw the triangles? If you know how to draw triangles, then you know where the triangles are.

Comment: Are you saying you have an OpenGL program which someone else compiled (i.e. all you have is the binary executable files)? ...and you want to somehow read a 2D screen shot to work out where the triangles etc. are?

Answer (score 4):

That's the wrong way around. You should save your data **before** giving it off to OpenGL. It's just wrong to first give the data to OpenGL, and then ask it back.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is make a 3D model editor and save the "Model". 
The triangles are not drawn in code, you just slap a triangle on the screen and move it around.
I'm just trying to get the triangles' coordinates that are currently on the screen. 
Think of it this way:
You have a triangle at the coordinates (0,0,0) whatever, when you move the triangle with the mouse, 
it changes the coordinates to, for example, (1,7,3).

Comment: @UserBLAHBLAHNumbers: Are you using a library or just plain C++ + OpenGL? Because __you__ are drawing the triangles, __not__ the user. You simply use the user input as, well, input.

Answer (score 2):

You fell for a misconception like so many other OpenGL newbies: You mistook OpenGL for a scene graph, which it is not. OpenGL is a *drawing* API. glTranslate, glRotate, glScale, they don't "position" objects, they change the way they are drawn.

It is your responsibility, as user of the OpenGL API, to keep track of all data that makes up the scene to draw. It's best to consider OpenGL as a one way machine: data goes in, but it doesn't come out (of course with some notable exceptions, but I advise you ignore them for the moment).

Comment: Exactly. You first tell OpenGL how the next object should be drawn (rotate, scaled, etc) and then you draw it. BAM - drawn, data gone.

Comment: Thankfully, all of those are removed now. We just need to direct newbies to the Core Profile.